# <div.main> </div.main> - Syntax

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, sass

I've seen this somewhere, but do not remember where:

```
<div.main> 
   // ....
</div.main> 
<div.secondary>
  // ....
</div.secondary>
```

Can somebody explain to me what this syntax is called, what it's used for, generally?

Comment: @Roy.B because I don't know any other frameworks and have worked mostly with React. So it's likely. Feel free to change this, if not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You may have seen it in some editors with some plugins like emmet(https://emmet.io/) or zen coding(https://code.google.com/archive/p/zen-coding/). These plugins helps to code html in a much faster way.

Answer (score 0):

That is not used anywhere, that I know of, like you have it in the actual HTML code.  However, in CSS you use the element.class with out the < & > symbols.  However in HTML5 you can use  for the main content of a page.

Taken from: [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp)

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The `<main>` tag specifies the main content of a document.
>
> The content inside the  element should be unique to the
>   document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across
>   documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information,
>   site logos, and search forms.
>
> Note: There must not be more than one  element in a document.
>   The  element must NOT be a descendant of an `<article>`,
>   `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.

I hope this helps.  The only other thing that I can think of is a custom interface that someone wrote that is not know or popular.  Some of the applications that I write have custom tags in them but I do not do anything like you asked.  Most of mine are {{tag}} for templates that need to be dynamic.

*Let's all help each other out.  At one point we were all new to programming.*

Comment: That's why I said "that I know of."  However, someone somewhere may have built something that does use that.

Comment: The problem with "that I know of." in this context, is that your answer amounts to "I don't know".

Comment: Splitting hairs here.  I did not know of any place that uses that exact code style.  However, I do now, thanks to Pons' answer.  Zen-coding uses that type of syntax.